# Jest and Enzyme simulating onDrag event for React unit testing

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, drag-and-drop, jestjs, enzyme

I have a problem with simulating **drag** event in my React Enzyme Jest unit test. Spy is never called in opposite to the **dragStart** and **dragExit**. Working ones are basing on mouse event and drag of course not - many tries of simulating it in strange ways like:
`wrapper.find('Draggable').simulate('mouseDown').simulate('mouseMove', {PageY: 100}).simulate('mouseUp');`

...are failed, so this is my actual describe block:

```
it('should call dragStart()', () => {
    wrapper.find('Draggable').simulate('mouseDown');
    expect(wrapper.instance().props.dragStart).toHaveBeenCalled(); // PASS
});
it('should call dragExit()', () => {
    wrapper.find('Draggable').simulate('mouseDown').simulate('mouseUp');
    expect(wrapper.instance().props.dragExit).toHaveBeenCalled(); // PASS
});
it('should call dragMove()', () => {
    wrapper.find('Draggable').simulate('drag');
    expect(wrapper.instance().props.dragMove).toHaveBeenCalled(); // FAIL
});
```

How can I simulate that dragging? I chose **react-draggable** dependency. I use enzyme **mount** with jest.fn() spy props to render my wrapper. Please for help and if you need any more information - just say! :)

PS: I know [Draggable solution with TestUtils](https://github.com/mzabriskie/react-draggable/blob/master/specs/draggable.spec.jsx#L712) but I want to create same effect with **Enzyme**, however my efforts are ending with not called spy at all:

```
wrapper.find('Draggable').simulate('mouseDown', {clientX: 0, clientY: 0}).simulate('mouseMove', {clientX: 0, clientY: 100}).simulate('mouseUp');
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity, how come testing the Draggable component? It looks like the dependency already has similar tests, without enzyme however: https://github.com/mzabriskie/react-draggable/blob/master/specs/draggable.spec.jsx#L63

Comment: @LukeHutton I have added PS to my post as a response to you.